# How to invite an existing user through devise_invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-invitable

I implemented

```
gem 'devise_invitable'
```

for model `User` and I am facing an issue while inviting an existing user. The error says `"USER IS ALREADY REGISTERED"`. I would like to add the same user in another `User` invited list. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a different implementation of the same problem, you can add the new behavior to the `InvitationsController` protected method, `invite_resource`.

A more verbose explanation of the example below can be found on the [DeviseInvitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) wiki page, titled [Invite a Resource (or User) that Has Already Signed Up without Invitation](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/wiki/Invite-a-Resource-(or-User)-that-Has-Already-Signed-Up-without-Invitation).

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController

  protected

  # invite_resource is called when creating invitation
  # should return an instance of resource class

  # this is devise_invitable's implementation
  # def invite_resource(&block)
  #   resource_class.invite!(invite_params, current_inviter, &block)
  # end

  def invite_resource(&block)
    @user = User.find_by(email: invite_params[:email])
    # @user is an instance or nil
    if @user && @user.email != current_user.email
      # invite! instance method returns a Mail::Message instance
      @user.invite!(current_user)
      # return the user instance to match expected return type
      @user
    else
      # invite! class method returns invitable var, which is a User instance
      resource_class.invite!(invite_params, current_inviter, &block)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks man - I ended up using this method to resend invitations because I was getting an 'email already exists' error trying to resend (even with devise config set to allow resending)

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, you'll need to create a new Invitations Controller that inherits from the original Devise::Invitations controller, but has modified logic in the create method.

The gem's [README](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) has a section on "Configuring Controllers" which describes this process. I also suggest having a look at the [source code for the parent controller](https://raw.github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/master/app/controllers/devise/invitations_controller.rb) as it will help provide some context.

I did something similar to what you desire, and used the Rails built-in method of `find_by_email`.  Here's some of the code I used...

```
def create
    # new user
    if User.find_by_email(invite_params[:email]).nil?
      super
    # existing user
    else
      @u = User.find_by_email!(invite_params[:email])
    ....more code that does what you want....
    end
  end
```

NOTE: Rails is smart and will use logic from the parent controller if no conflicting instructions are given the child controller you create. The point is that you don't need to re-write the whole controller.  Ideally, you'll just make your modifications in the child controller then call `super` to revert back to the same method in the parent controller to finish the action.